# Retrieving data in shuffled order from SQL (Android)

Tags: android, sql

There are many ways to do shuffling of data, but I wonder if an Android DB can do it for me.

In other words is the a way to have in Android SQL something like "ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME shuffled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by [`RANDOM`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mainTable ORDER BY RANDOM()", null);
```